# Why when a new form opens, one of the buttons is highlighted in blue?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, windowsformshost

I don't understand why when a new form opens, one of the buttons is highlighted in blue.
How can I fix that?[In the picture you can see the problem, it's happens in every Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj4gK.png)

Comment: That is the focus rectangle, useful when operating the UI with the keyboard instead of the mouse.  Press the spacebar, press Tab.  Set the TabIndex property of these controls correctly so the tab order is natural and you get the first focus the way you want it.

Answer (score 2):

Without code, I suspect that the highlighted button is the last one that you placed onto the designer and this will leave it as the default control in focus.

It's usually good practice to set focus, visibility, enable and tab order controls manually if you want them to be something specific.